# How to determine the filtered average / filtered max over a range in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

For a pivot table in which we track 2 types of items we currently only calculate the max and average time an item is open for all tickets.
But we would like to have it per type.

**The table**

I'm not allowed to share the exact pivot table since it contains customer data, so I can only describe it below using a table

table-column letters (first is empty since it are the row-numbers)
| | A  |    B    |   C    |    D        |     E         |  F   |

| 1 | Id | Summary | Status | Closed date | Time open (d) | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | bogus | Open |  | 1 | Type1 |
| 3 | 2 | bogus2 | Closed | 01/01/2023 | 3 | Type1 |
| 4 | 3 | bogus3 | In Review |  | 5 | Type1 |
| 5 | 4 | bogus | Open |  | 1 | Type2 |

** Formulas **

We currently use the following formulas to calculate the average / max time a ticket is open using the following formulas:

Average: `=average(if(isblank(D2:D5),E2:E5))` (= 2.33)
Max `=max(if(isblank(D2:D5),E2:E5))` (=5)

But these answers 2.33 and 5 mix up both types.
I'm looking for a way to add a filter in the formulas so they also look at the 'Type' column and only when the 'Type' is equal it uses it. So the answers for 'Type1' should be `Average=3` and `MAX=5`

I know there is `AVERAGEIF`, but when I tried it I get `#SPILL!`:
AverageIf: `=AVERAGEIF(IF(ISBLANK(D2:D5),E2:E5), pivot_table[Type]="Type1")`
And I get `#DIV/0!` if I try:
AverageIf: `=AVERAGEIF(E2:E5, OR(ISBLANK(D2:D5),pivot_table[Type]="Type1"))`

I'm not a big star with excel so I was already happy that I found the AverageIf formula, but I'm stuck with how I should solve it. Hence my question if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `AVERAGEIFS()` function:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(E2:E5,D2:D5,"",F2:F5,"Type1")
```